# How to set different colors for dots on LineChart at ios charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I need to paint values in one range to yellow and other range to red. How to implement it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an much easier ways to color the circles differently. Here is an example which colors each circle with an random color. But you could also think about a conditional coloring like color each circle in red which y-value is greater than 10 or any other condition.

```
var yValues: [ChartDataEntry] = []           // y-values
var xValues: [String?] = []                  // x-values
var set: LineChartDataSet                    // value set (x- and y-values)
var circleColors: [NSUIColor] = []           // arrays with circle color definitions

for i in 0..< xValues.count {
    let red   = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
    let blue  = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
    circleColors.append(color)
}

// set colors and enable value drawing    
set.colors = circleColors
set.drawValuesEnabled = true
set.valueFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
```

Comment: Thanks Morpheus78! One thing, i couldn't set the colors property directly because the compiler gave me an error, saying it was a "get only property". So, i used the set.circleColors property instead and it worked like a charm

Comment: @NahuelRoldan, you're right. There was a change in the charts API in one of the last release.